# Degree of extension $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[4]{5},\sqrt[6]{7})$.

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials, minimal-polynomials

I tried to consider the tower of extension $\Bbb Q\subset \Bbb Q(\sqrt[6]{7})\subset\Bbb Q(\sqrt[4]{5},\sqrt[6]{7})$.

The minimal polynomial of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[6]{7})$ over $\Bbb Q$ is $x^6-7$ by Eisenstein. But although it is easy to see that it has no root in $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[6]{7})$, how can I formally conclude that $x^4-5$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[6]{7})$ and thus we can see the basis of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[6]{7}, \sqrt[4]{5})$？

I know that for if we have the degree of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[6]{7})$ and $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[4]{5})$ are coprime, then it can be much simpler. But how to deal with that in this case where they are not coprime. Any help would be appreciate. Thanks so much！

Comment: You might check through linear algebra that the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt[6]{7}+\sqrt[4]{5}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ has degree $24$. Since $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[6]{7}+\sqrt[4]{5})\subseteq\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[6]{7},\sqrt[4]{5})$ the extensions through $\sqrt[6]{7}$ and $\sqrt[4]{5}$ are independent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The polynomial $x^4-5$ can be factored over $\mathbb{R}$, which contains $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[6]{7})$, as
$$
x^4-5=(x-\sqrt[4]{5})(x+\sqrt[4]{5})(x^2+\sqrt{5})
$$
Thus a factorization over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[6]{7})$ can only be the one above or $(x^2-\sqrt{5})(x^2+\sqrt{5})$. So you just need to show that $\sqrt{5}\notin\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[6]{7})$.

Suppose $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})\subseteq\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[6]{7})$. Then the degree of $\sqrt[6]{7}$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$ is $3$ by the dimension formula. The factorization of $x^6-7$ over $\mathbb{R}$ is
$$
(x^3-\sqrt{7})(x^3+\sqrt{7})=
(x-\sqrt[6]{7})(x^2+\sqrt[6]{7}\,x+\sqrt[3]{7})
(x+\sqrt[6]{7})(x^2-\sqrt[6]{7}\,x+\sqrt[3]{7})
$$
Since $\sqrt{7}\notin\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$, you can only get degree three factors as
$$
(x-\sqrt[6]{7})(x^2-\sqrt[6]{7}\,x+\sqrt[3]{7})
$$
or
$$
(x+\sqrt[6]{7})(x^2+\sqrt[6]{7}\,x+\sqrt[3]{7})
$$
and in both cases you'd conclude that $\sqrt[6]{7}\in\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$, which is impossible.

---

Suppose $x^4-5$ can be factored as $f(x)g(x)$ over some extension $K$ of $\mathbb{Q}$, $K\subseteq\mathbb{R}$; suppose also that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are non constant. Since $x^4-5$ is monic, also $f$ and $g$ can be assumed monic. Continuing like this, we can assume that $x^4-5$ is factored into *monic* factors, irreducible over $K[x]$.

Let $h(x)\in K[x]$ be one of these factors; its factorization in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ must consist of polynomials in the set $\{x-\sqrt[4]{5},x+\sqrt[4]{5},x+\sqrt{5}\}$, which are the irreducible factors of $x^4-5$ in $\mathbb{R}[x]$, because of uniqueness of factorization in $F[x]$ (for $F$ any field).

Now it's just a matter of checking the various possibilities. A factorization of $x^4-5$ can only be with degrees

- $1$, $1$ and $2$
- $2$ and $2$
- $1$ and $3$

If a degree $1$ factor appears, then $\sqrt[4]{5}\in K$; if a degree $2$ factor appears, then $\sqrt{5}\in K$. In both cases, $\sqrt{5}\in K$.

The same argument applies for the second part of the proof.

Comment: Thanks! But may I please ask how can we see that the factorization over $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[6]{7})$ is either $(x−\sqrt[4]{5})(x+\sqrt[4]{5})(x^2+\sqrt{5})$ or $(x^2-\sqrt{5})(x^2+\sqrt{5})$, which can allow us to conclude that it it factorize then $\sqrt{5}\in \Bbb Q(\sqrt[6]{7})$?

Comment: @ymxu0809 If a factorization exist over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[6]{7}$, this is also a factorization over the reals. We know what the irreducible factors are over the reals, so a factorization over the smaller field must be obtained from one over the larger field. This is used also in the final argument.

Comment: Thanks! I do know that the factorization comes from $\Bbb R$, but how can I see that the only possible ways we can gain the factorization over $\Bbb R$ must involves the existence of $\sqrt{5}$? That is, how to see that there is not possible that we can have $5=abcd$ or $5=abc$ or $5=ab$ where $a,b,c,d\in\Bbb R$ but none of them involves $\sqrt{5}$?

Comment: @ymxu0809 If $x^4-5$ factors in some number field $K\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, then its factorization contains one among $x-\sqrt[4]{5}$, $x+\sqrt[4]{5}$ or $x^2-\sqrt{5}$; thus $\sqrt{5}$ must belong to $K$. Remember that factorization in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ is unique.

Comment: Yes it intuitively makes sence to me... But how can I see that 5 can never be a product of transendental elements or some product of **other** algebraic number where $\sqrt{5}$ does not appear? Is that the fact that as the factorization is unique, once we have a factorization already, we cannot have another factorization?

Comment: Also I think that it is possible to factorize it as $(x-\sqrt[4]{5})(x-\sqrt[4]{5})(x-\sqrt[4]{5})(x-\sqrt[4]{5})$, which also implies the existence of $\sqrt{5}$.

Comment: @ymxu0809 I added the full argument

Answer (score 2):

In general, we have the following: Let $ K/\mathbf Q $ and $ L/\mathbf Q $ be two number fields such that there exists a rational prime $ p $ which is totally ramified in $ K/\mathbf Q $ and unramified in $ L/\mathbf Q $. Then, the extensions $ K/\mathbf Q $ and $ L/\mathbf Q $ are linearly disjoint, that is, $ [KL : \mathbf Q] = [K : \mathbf Q][L : \mathbf Q] $.

**Proof.** Let $ \mathfrak q $ be a prime of $ LK $ lying over the rational prime $ p $. Then, $ e_{\mathfrak q | p} \geq [K : \mathbf Q] $, since ramification indices are multiplicative across towers and $ p $ is totally ramified in $ K/\mathbf Q $.  On the other hand, if we let $ \mathfrak p $ be the prime of $ L $ lying below $ \mathfrak q $; then we have that

$$ [K : \mathbf Q] \leq e_{\mathfrak q | p} = e_{\mathfrak q | \mathfrak p} e_{\mathfrak p | p} = e_{\mathfrak q | \mathfrak p} \leq [LK : L] $$

However, we obviously have that $ [K : \mathbf Q] \geq [LK : L] $; thus it follows that $ [K : \mathbf Q] = [LK : L] $, and multiplication by $ [L : \mathbf Q] $ on both sides of the equality gives the result.

Now, notice that we have exactly the situation of this claim with the rational prime $ p = 5 $, which is totally ramified in $ \mathbf Q(\sqrt[4]{5}) $ but unramified in $ \mathbf Q(\sqrt[6]{7}) $.

Comment: It seems to be a quite general argument. But as I have not learnt about the terminology **ramified**, could you please give some explaination on this word? And for the set $LK$, do you mean the set $\lbrace lk: l\in L, k\in K\rbrace$?

Answer (score 0):

To show that the polynomial $X^4-5$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[6]{7})$ you must assume that it is not irreducible,thus it can be factorized to polynomials of degree:$1* 1* 1* 1$ or $2*2$ or $3*1$ or $2*1*1$.

You have to work by cases but its difficult because you have complicated elements in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[6]{7})$ thus consider the opposite tower.

If you prove it then a basis for the  final extension will be:

$A=\{\sqrt[6]{7}^j*\sqrt[4]{5}^i|j=0,1...5 ,i=0,1,2,3,\}$

This is one way but it has many calculations.